# Invoke the Ribbon Split button of outlook from outlook add-in

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I have a custom Ribbon Split button in outlook. I ideally want to invoke the top button of the split button(not the drop down) from my outlook Add-in. To do that I got the control of split button using Redemption and when i try to execute it I am getting IAccessible Error.I am able to invoke any other normal button with this approach. I googled around all things but not able to find the solution. Any help or suggestion will be of great help.  below code shows how I got the control of button

```
Redemption.SafeRibbonControl newControl = cRibbon.Controls.Item("Add With Template");
newControl.Execute();
```

Comment: Have you tried to use Inspect (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) to see if you can invoke any of the subitems?

Comment: No i have not tried invoking sub items(No idea to invoke that). I want to know whether is it possible to invoke top button part of Split button?If i get that my job is done.

Comment: I am not able find why i am getting this error. All other normal button are executing. Is it not possible to invoke split button using redemption?

Comment: Yes, Redemption uses the accessibility API to invoke the default action on that button. If you can access the subitem with Redemption, you should be able to execute it.

Comment: When i try to execute the default action on that split button I am getting error ` Error in IAccessible.accDoDefaultAction: MAPI_E_CALL_FAILED`. (Above in the code specifies the way i tried to execute the button) What is the alternate way that i can execute this button(other than the way i did above)?

Comment: Have you tried to use inspect.exe?

Comment: Is there any other way i can do it? I don't know how to use inspect. What exactly is the problem? Why i am not able to invoke the split button where in i am able to invoke other normal button which exist in same ribbon.

Comment: That's a question that only Microsoft can answer...

Comment: Okiee....Can you suggest me how i can use inspect?

Comment: When inspect.exe is running, it tracks your selection in Outlook's ribbon. Once you get to the button you want, click Actions | DoDefaultAction in inspect.exe.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try with inspect.

Comment: No use of using inspect. Should i have to use MSAA API's to do this? If so do i have to add any references to my project?

Comment: "No use of using inspect"? Do you not see the button you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah i am able to find the button. If i click on the button it performs the action but not able to see which method it is calling

Comment: "find the button" using inspect.exe?

Comment: yeah using inspect i am able to see.