# Programmatically invoking the drop down item in C# form Outlook Add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption, split-button

I have a outlook add-in from which i want to invoke Ribbon Split button's drop down item using Redemption . This split button is a custom button created from other add-in. I want to access in my add-in. For detailed explanation check the below link.[Invoking the Ribbon Split button using redemption](http://openstackwiki.org/wiki/Fehler_in_IAccessible.accDoDefaultAction_MAPI_E_CALL_FAILED_Ausf%C3%BChrung_Dropdown-Men%C3%BC-Eintrag_mit_Erl%C3%B6sung_mit_demselben_Namen) When i tried accessing I am getting same error. Can some one help me to solve this problem.
Here i am trying to invoke drop down item where in the other post that was trying to invoke button of the split button and moreover i have attached image which is very clear.
Check the image in the link.
(The link post was already posted by some one else in the stack overflow long back)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoke the Ribbon Split button of outlook from outlook add-in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866487/invoke-the-ribbon-split-button-of-outlook-from-outlook-add-in)

Comment: I am not supposed to use inspect. I want any other approach to get this done. I ideally have to get the control of the " Add with template" and perform default action on that button.

Comment: As other posters have stated, you have no choice but to use the Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA) interfaces for automating Ribbon interactions. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404170.aspx and https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSOfficeRibbonAccessibility-cd7fe67f

Comment: Thank you. I read through the links. In that it was mentioned on split button control we can perform accDefaultAction but in my code where i took the control of the button through redemption i am not getting anything as such accDefaultAction. How can we get accDefaultAction on split button?

Comment: You may need to use the MSAA APIs directly instead of through Redemption, which is just a wrapper and doesn't have the full functionality of the MSAA APIs.

Comment: Ok. Can you guide me how to use MSAA API to get this done?

Comment: I have no experience with the MSAA API unfortunately. Feel free to create a new topic to address any specific questions you may have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access buttons freely in the Office Ribbon, as was possible with the CommandBars interface - no matter what the programming language. This was a design decision on the part of Microsoft.

There are provisions for accessing the built-in controls provided by the Office application, as have been mentioned by others: CommandBars.ExecuteMso and the Accessibility APIs. These do *not* work for custom buttons, however.

It is possible to "share" another add-in's Ribbon controls, provided that add-in has used a namespace and the idQ attribute for the controls it shares. This does not enable your code to run the other add-ins code, however. (See this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12))

The only possibility, but it's not a reliable one, is to use SendKeys (emulate the user typing) to send the Alt+keyboard shortcut combination for the command. The reason this is not reliable is because Office can alter the shortcut at any time, if it conflicts with any other shortcut present at that particular moment in the UI.

Comment: Thank you for the reply cindy. Is there a way to access top button of split button("Add WIth Template" not drop down one) programmatically? Do i have to use SendKeys only for that?

Comment: SendKeys is your only option. UNLESS the person who wrote the other add-in exposes that class "publicly" so that you could call it directly (in other words, *not* using the Ribbon).

Comment: Okie..  Is that it should be used on button control?? I actually tried using it on button control that i took it from redemption. Its not working,. any material to refer to know about sendkeys that i can use here. ?

Comment: Hi cindy ..Thanks for the suggestion . Its working.

Comment: How can i click on the Add with Template Split button? .(not the drop down add with template).

Comment: All you can do is use Alt then look at the command sequence for the keyboard to trigger that command. I can't possilby tell you what that might be...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute an action of any control in Office applications you need to use the [ExecuteMso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx) method of the CommandBars class (see Explorer.CommandBars or Inspector.CommandBars). It allows to execute the control identified by the idMso parameter. Here is what MSDN states for the method:

This method is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in buttons, toggleButtons and splitButtons. On failure it returns E_InvalidArg for an invalid IdMso, and E_Fail for controls that are not enabled or not visible.

You can find the list of built-in controls in the following documents:

- [Office 2010 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627)
- [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)
- [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)

In case if you need to run an action of any custom control which comes from another add-in you can call an event handler directly by using the late-binding technology represented by Reflection in .Net. See [Type.InvokeMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method for more information. The approach is described in depth in the [Calling Code in VSTO Add-ins from Other Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608621.aspx) article.

Comment: Hi Eugene. I have gone through it and found using commandbar object is the way to do.In commandbar i have a method called Findcontrol which is asking the control Id. How can we find the control Id in C#? Button is a custom button.

Comment: @Vikram `FindControl` only works for the old (pre 2007) Toolbars. It does *not* work for the Ribbon.